# Collapse column only on mobile view and collapse row only on desktop view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on my web application in Yii2. Here is the html layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3><?php echo $value['strategy_title']; ?></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $value['strategy_description']; ?></p>
                    <p><button  class="btn btn-info btn-holder" 
                                type="button" 
                                data-toggle="collapse" 
                                data-target="#<?php echo $value['strategy_title']; ?>"
                                aria-expanded="false" 
                                aria-controls="<?php echo $value['strategy_title']; ?>">
                        Know more
                    </button></p>
                    <div class="collapse" id="<?php echo $value['strategy_title']; ?>">
                        <p>
                            <!-- Here is the column chart -->
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse" id="<?php echo $value['strategy_title']; ?>">
        <p>
            <!-- Here is the row chart -->
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is only a part of the whole page. So what i am actually working with is thumbnails gallery with collapse button, which toggle Highchar.js hidden inside Collapse block. So when the page is in mobile view state i want to make the collapse button toggle chart`s block below it self, like on the picture.
[image] Otherwise when page is in desktop view state i want to make the collapse button toggle row, here is the example on the picture. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I made it, but i guess my solution may be not correct. So i made 2 buttons with defferent classes

```
<p><button  class="btn btn-info btn-holder-xs" 
                            type="button" 
                            data-toggle="collapse" 
                            data-target="#<?php echo $value['strategy_title'] . "-xs"; ?>"
                            aria-expanded="false" 
                            aria-controls="<?php echo $value['strategy_title'] . "-xs"; ?>">
                    Узнать больше
                </button></p>
                <p><button  class="btn btn-info btn-holder-md" 
                            type="button" 
                            data-toggle="collapse" 
                            data-target="#<?php echo $value['strategy_title']; ?>"
                            aria-expanded="false" 
                            aria-controls="<?php echo $value['strategy_title']; ?>">
                    Узнать больше
                </button></p>
```

Then i wrote some css @media

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
.btn-holder-xs {
    display: block;
}
.btn-holder-md {
    display: none;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .btn-holder-xs {
        display: none;
    }
    .btn-holder-md {
        display: block;
    }
}
```